# Any way when I readjust my browser's width, boxes go into one column?

Tags: html, css, browser, width, multiple-columns

```
<div class="container" style="display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
display: flex;
margin-bottom: 25px;
flex-wrap: wrap;
    ">
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<div class="box" style=" width: 50%; height: 340px; display:flex; border-style: dotted; border-width: 1px; border-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);  flex-direction: column; max-width: 265px; align-items: left; justify-content: left;  margin: 0px; 
    text-align: left;"><a href="http://www.example.com/" style="text-align: center; top: 25px;"><img font-family:lucida="" sans="" src="/images/contentimages/images/KN95_Mask.png" style="width: 208px; height: 208px; display: block; margin: auto; position: relative; top: 10px;" /><strong><span style="font-size:20px;"><span style="font-family:lucida sans unicode,lucida grande,sans-serif;"></span></span></strong></a><strong></strong><br />
<span style="font-size:18px;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; KN95 Masks<a href="https://dummyimage.com/350x300/000/fff" style="color: rgb(116, 15, 110); text-align: center; top: 25px;"><span style="font-size: 18px;">&nbsp;</span></a><span style="font-weight: bolder;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<a class="btn btn-info btn-sm edatalayer order-1" data-list="product-listing-page" data-position="1" data-purl="custom-business-forms" href="http://www.example.com/">View details <i class="far fa-chevron-right pl-1"></i></a>&nbsp; &nbsp; </span></span></div>

<div class="box" style=" width: 50%; height: 340px; display:flex; border-style: dotted; border-width: 1px; border-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);  flex-direction: column; max-width: 265px; align-items: left; justify-content: left;  margin: 0px; 
    text-align: left;"><a href="http://www.example.com/" style="text-align: center; top: 25px;"><img font-family:lucida="" sans="" src="/images/contentimages/images/Exam_Gloves.png" style="width: 208px; height: 208px; display: block; margin: auto; position: relative; top: 10px;" /><strong><span style="font-size:20px;"><span style="font-family:lucida sans unicode,lucida grande,sans-serif;"></span></span></strong></a><strong></strong><br />
<span style="font-size:18px;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Exam Gloves<span style="font-weight: bolder;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="btn btn-info btn-sm edatalayer order-1" data-list="product-listing-page" data-position="1" data-purl="custom-business-forms" href="http://www.example.com/">View details <i class="far fa-chevron-right pl-1"></i></a>&nbsp; &nbsp; </span></span></div>

<div class="box" style=" width: 50%; height: 340px; display:flex; border-style: dotted; border-width: 1px; border-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);  flex-direction: column; max-width: 265px; align-items: left; justify-content: left;  margin: 0px; 
    text-align: left;"><a href="http://www.example.com/" style="text-align: center; top: 25px;"><img font-family:lucida="" sans="" src="/images/contentimages/images/Floor_Decals.png" style="width: 208px; height: 208px; display: block; margin: auto; position: relative; top: 10px;" /><strong><span style="font-size:20px;"><span style="font-family:lucida sans unicode,lucida grande,sans-serif;"></span></span></strong></a><strong></strong><br />
<span style="font-size:18px;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Floor Decals<a href="https://dummyimage.com/350x300/000/fff" style="color: rgb(116, 15, 110); text-align: center; top: 25px;"><span style="font-size: 18px;">&nbsp;</span></a><span style="font-weight: bolder;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="btn btn-info btn-sm edatalayer order-1" data-list="product-listing-page" data-position="1" data-purl="custom-business-forms" href="http://www.example.com/">View details <i class="far fa-chevron-right pl-1"></i></a>&nbsp; &nbsp; </span></span></div>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

[image: Columns]

Currently when my browser becomes more narrower, my boxes end up like what you see in the above picture, when I want them to be in one giant column.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to set the container grid and not flex. In a flex layout your images will try to use up the space they find, while in a grid they follow your grid template for each media query(screen size). Another option would be to set flex-basis to size your images relative to the container.